# Haskell: functions in custom data types

Tags: haskell, custom-data-type

if I have a custom data type that takes in a string representation of a `Boolean` (ie `"true"` or `"false"`). How do I make by data type convert that to a `Bool` with out having to perform an actions on the input before?

for example

```
λ: MyData "false"
MyData False
```

Comment: A data type can't “take” anything, like a string representation of a boolean. It can possible _contain_ such a representation, is that what you mean? — It seems like you're basically just asking how to implement the function `f :: String -> Bool` which fulfills `f "false" = False`. ...or what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't without a function, normally you just define a function that returns the new type, for instance:

```
newtype MyData = MyData Bool

myData :: String -> MyData
myData "false" = MyData False
myData "true" = MyData True
-- Need to decide how to handle invalid arguments
```

Now instead of writing `MyData "false"` you write `myData "false"`.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there was an implementation that any input that the `MyData` constructor was used on would automatically run that function first. This is pretty much how I was implementing it but it felt like  a work around

Comment: @matthias No, it's by design. Constructors are dumb and can't do anything to their arguments. Functions are smart.

Comment: @matthias: Constructors are dumb because otherwise deconstructing them in patterns would be non-sensical. `f (MyData True) = ...` is weird when you call it with `f (MyData "true")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `OverloadedStrings` extension in GHC and declare your type to be an instance of `IsString`:

```
newtype MyData = MyData Bool deriving (Show)

instance IsString MyData where
    fromString "false" = MyData False
    fromString "true" = MyData True
    fromString "False" = MyData False
    fromString "True" = MyData True
```

Now you can say something like:

```
> "false" :: MyData
MyData False
> "True" :: MyData
MyData True
```

Comment: Yes, this is possible, but I really don't think this would be a reasonable approach here. Pretty sure a simple _function_ is the right way to go for the OP. `fromString` would fail very weirdly on incompatible inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't.

First, `String` type has values irrepresentable as `Boolean`, like `"foo"`. What do your datatype supposed to return on `MyData "foo"`? an `error`?

Second, there is the part of haskell philosophy: do everything explicitly. No typecasts, no `Foo foo = 1` which calls `foo(const int&)` like in C++. And that is a good part.

P.S.: if you get the values from input, just write yourself a proper parser (not just a `Read` instance - it crushes thread on failure).